# The program after if statement is not executing

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a problem with escaping from if, my code looks more or less like this in python:

```
if answear == "Yes":
    do something 
    pylab.show()
if anwear == "No":
    do something
    pylab.show()
answear2= input("How are you?")
print ("I'm here")
```

The problem is that is statement works nicely but after showing the plot, new input is not shown , neither printing. How is that possible? Where the program stacks?

Comment: Is the `anwear` in second `if` a typo?

Comment: I'll be honest.  I don't trust any of those variables.  I'm not sure if these are typos or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The show method is blocking in pylab. If you close your gui window, your program will continue.

If you do not want it to be blocking, use multithreading (look at the threading module).